# Store Set object in Redis database with Scala

Tags: scala, redis, set

I'd like to store a Set of Ints in Redis with Scala

I have this code

```
val redis = new RedisClient("localhost", 6379)

val mySet = Set(4,5,6,7,8)

redis.set("myKey", mySet)
redis.get("myKey")
```

It returns a String:

```
res1: Option[String] = Some(Set(5, 6, 7, 8, 4))
```

How can I do redis to store my set in an efficient way and return it instead of String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be efficient, use Redis commands for sets: SADD / SMEMBERS. You use GET / SET, which are **string** commands, which means they accept and return strings.

Also, I am not familiar with Scala driver, but I suspect that its SMEMBERS implementation will return an array/set of strings, even though you set values as integers. This is because Redis protocol is text based and *everything* is passed as a string. That being said, scala driver might get clever and try converting values for you, I don't know. But if you get strings, don't be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

SET/GET are used for setting and getting strings in redis.If you are using

```
val mySet = Set(4,5,6,7,8)    
redis.set("myKey", mySet)
```

then the redis will accept the value in "myset" variable as string type.
If you want to store a set then use following commands ,you need to give values of set separately ,not in a variable(the way i did it)

```
redis.SADD("myKey",4,5,6,7)
```

for getting value of a set from redis

```
redis.SMEMBERS("myKey")
```

and it will be more efficient, if you use

```
val redis = new RedisClientPool("localhost", 6379)
```

instead of

```
val redis = new RedisClient("localhost", 6379)
```